# How to Find and Replace worksheet name in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 100 worksheets with different names saved in a folder. I have another worksheet in another folder where I conduct analysis of data from one of those 100 worksheets. In this analysis worksheet, I have formulas containing name of a worksheet. While all such formulas remain same, I need to change the name of worksheet to another worksheet. How can I do it? Please, help asap.

Comment: If you need to change the external reference often, then consider using the INDIRECT() function. You can then store the external spreadsheet name in a cell and reference it in your formulae. See Excel help for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but I think I understand it.

Basically you have a spreadsheet which gets information from a spreedsheet in another document and then does something with it. What you want to do is do the exact same thing for information taken from 100 different documents.

To get information from a spreedsheet in another document you need to use the following syntex in your formula...

```
='[DOCUMENT-NAME]SPREEDSHEET-NAME'!CELL
```

For example, to get the information in cell `A1` in spreedsheet `Sheet 1` from document `one` you need to write:

```
='[one]Sheet 1'!A1
```

Now you "just" need to change the information in each formula as needed, how you do this all depends on your naming system. Without more information about the names of each documents and the spreedsheets used it is impossible to give you more help.

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question. I clarify my question further: I have saved daily quotes (historical data) i.e. open price, high price, low price, close price, volume etc., for 100 stocks - named IBM, Microsoft, Apple etc. individually in a folder. Now, my new worksheet named My Analysis contains formulas that takes data from the IBM worksheet. While all formulas remain same, I just need to change the name from IBM to Microsoft so I get all data for analysis as all Stock worksheets contain fixed ranges, only data variable. Pls, help me now asap. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you look at my second line of "code" (highlighted in grey) in my answer, you should have something similar to this in your My Analysis document, simply replace the word "one" (which would be "IBM" in your case I think) with the next document name (I imagine "Microsoft").