# how to change worksheet name in formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have saved daily quotes (historical data) i.e. open price, high price, low price, close price, volume etc., for 100 stocks - named IBM, Microsoft, Apple etc. individually in a folder. Now, my new worksheet named My Analysis contains formulas that takes data from the IBM worksheet. While all formulas remain same, I just need to change the name from IBM to Microsoft so I get all data for analysis as all Stock worksheets contain fixed ranges, only data variable. Pls, help me now asap. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't [double post](http://superuser.com/questions/551976/how-to-find-and-replace-worksheet-name-in-a-formula). Edit your first question if you feel it needs more clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use *Search&Replace*: Replace all occurrences of `IBM` with `Microsoft`. Make sure that it is written exactly as you named your file names - and that both source files are either both open or both closed.